# How to install AFNI

Tags: software-installation

These are the instructions given to me for installing AFNI, yet when I completed them, it still tells me 'command not found' for the 'afni' command.

```
sudo yum install libXp tcsh
sudo yum install PyQt4 R
```

(This was not correct, but I was able to get it to work with this):

```
sudo apt-get install libxp6 tcsh
sudo apt-get install python-qt4 r-base
```

Then:

```
cd
mkdir abin
```

Then it says to choose one of these binaries.  I wasn't sure which one to choose, but I chose #3:

1. linux_openmp     : for multi-CPU systems, (needs libgomp)
2. linux_openmp_64  : 64-bit version of the same
3. linux_xorg7      : otherwise current linux package
4. linux_xorg7_64   : 64-bit version of the same

Then:

```
set package = linux_xorg7
wget http://afni.nimh.nih.gov/pub/dist/tgz/$package.tgz
tar xvfz $package.tgz
mv $package/* abin
rmdir $package
```

and finally, add the AFNI package directory ~/abin to your path:

```
echo 'set path = ( $path ~/abin )' >> ~/.cshrc
```

Then it said to log out and log back in so the programs are recognized in the path, and then to try these commands upon login:

```
afni
suma
uber_subject.py
```

Only the last one worked.  The others said 'command not found'.

What went wrong?

When I do 'echo $path' it shows this:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /home/owner/abin /home/owner/abin
```

The output of ls -l /home/owner/abin is:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2134 Nov 29 21:01 @Install_AfniRetinoDemo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1892 Nov 29 21:01 @Install_FATCAT_DEMO
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3465 Nov 29 21:01 @Install_InstaCorr_Demo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1683 Nov 29 21:01 @Install_MEICA_Demo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5269 Nov 29 21:01 @Install_RSFMRI_Motion_Group_Demo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2609 Nov 29 21:01 @Install_TSrestMovieDemo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      902 Nov 29 21:01 @isOblique
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3864 Nov 29 21:01 @IsoMasks
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11329870 Nov 29 21:01 IsoSurface
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3521 Nov 29 21:01 killer.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    18132 Nov 29 21:01 Level2.R
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   101340 Nov 29 21:01 lib_afni1D.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner   221272 Nov 29 21:01 libcoxplot.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner   220774 Nov 29 21:01 libf2c.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    18582 Nov 29 20:53 libGLws.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner  1299298 Nov 29 21:00 libgts.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11671 Nov 29 21:01 lib_matplot.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner  8400460 Nov 29 21:01 libmri.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner   750488 Nov 29 21:01 libmrix.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    67662 Nov 29 21:01 lib_qt_gui.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    61316 Nov 30 14:40 lib_qt_gui.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    17868 Nov 29 21:01 lib_realtime.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3929 Nov 29 21:01 lib_RR_plot.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    55020 Nov 29 21:01 lib_subjects.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    46258 Nov 30 14:40 lib_subjects.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner  7842396 Nov 29 20:57 libSUMA.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    29947 Nov 29 21:01 lib_surf_clustsim.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     8194 Nov 29 21:01 lib_system_check.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    10148 Nov 29 21:01 lib_textdata.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     9272 Nov 30 14:40 lib_textdata.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    33042 Nov 29 21:01 lib_timing.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    31904 Nov 29 21:01 lib_uber_align.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    23453 Nov 29 21:01 lib_uber_skel.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    66434 Nov 29 21:01 lib_uber_subject.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    55296 Nov 30 14:40 lib_uber_subject.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    23340 Nov 29 21:01 lib_uber_ttest.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner   258384 Nov 29 21:01 libvolpack.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4517 Nov 29 21:01 lib_wx.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2432 Nov 29 21:01 list_struct.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    23775 Nov 29 21:01 lpc_align.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    16378 Nov 29 21:01 machdep.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11268219 Nov 29 21:01 MakeColorMap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    33562 Nov 29 21:01 @MakeLabelTable
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8745 Nov 29 21:01 @make_plug_diff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4141 Nov 29 21:01 make_pq_script.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    91329 Nov 29 21:01 make_random_timing.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    15388 Nov 29 21:01 @make_stim_file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11915 Nov 29 21:01 make_stim_times.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11282021 Nov 29 21:01 MapIcosahedron
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3496097 Nov 29 20:52 map_TrackID
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     9080 Nov 29 20:46 mayo_analyze
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3975 Nov 29 21:01 mcw_glob.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3483 Nov 29 21:01 mcw_malloc.h
drwxr-xr-x 4 owner owner     4096 Nov 29 20:33 meica.libs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    26764 Nov 29 20:33 meica.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1088640 Nov 29 20:33 mgh_wh_template+tlrc.BRIK
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3246 Nov 29 20:33 mgh_wh_template+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      141 Nov 29 21:01 misc_math.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner  6244968 Nov 29 20:33 MNI152_1mm_uni+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     4686 Nov 29 20:33 MNI152_1mm_uni+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1726099 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_colin27_T1_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2309 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_colin27_T1_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3657483 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_gw_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2658 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_gw_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   166760 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_lr_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2771 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_lr_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   270372 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_ml_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    18038 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_ml_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   238153 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_mpm_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11872 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_mpm_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1726099 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_N27+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2309 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_N27+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3240810 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_pmaps_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    18134 Nov 29 20:33 MNIa_caez_pmaps_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   861626 Nov 29 20:33 MNI_avg152T2+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4983 Nov 29 20:33 MNI_avg152T2+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1726099 Nov 29 20:33 MNI_caez_N27+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2764 Nov 29 20:33 MNI_caez_N27+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   266078 Nov 29 20:33 MNI_EPI+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4631 Nov 29 20:33 MNI_EPI+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5545 Nov 29 20:52 model_beta.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5160 Nov 29 20:52 model_constant.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    13916 Nov 29 20:52 model_conv_cosine4.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    15035 Nov 29 20:52 model_conv_diffgamma.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8883 Nov 29 20:52 model_convgamma2a.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8183 Nov 29 20:52 model_convgamma.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    31047 Nov 29 20:52 model_demri_3.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5416 Nov 29 20:52 model_diffexp.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5262 Nov 29 20:52 model_diffusion.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5598 Nov 29 20:52 model_expMEMRI3.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5309 Nov 29 20:52 model_expMEMRI.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     9428 Nov 29 20:52 model_expr2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5248 Nov 29 20:52 model_exp.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5457 Nov 29 20:52 model_gammavar.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5346 Nov 29 20:52 model_linear.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5450 Nov 29 20:52 model_linplusort.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     9364 Nov 29 20:52 model_michaelis_menton.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5089 Nov 29 20:52 model_null.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5289 Nov 29 20:52 model_quadratic.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5686 Nov 29 20:52 model_sinewave_apf.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5345 Nov 29 20:52 model_sinewave_ap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5447 Nov 29 20:52 model_squarewave_apf.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5382 Nov 29 20:52 model_squarewave_ap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5546 Nov 29 20:52 model_trnglwave_apf.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5485 Nov 29 20:52 model_trnglwave_ap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5088 Nov 29 20:52 model_zero.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8004 Nov 29 21:01 module_test_lib.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     6312 Nov 30 14:40 module_test_lib.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4947 Nov 29 21:01 @move.to.series.dirs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   206652 Nov 29 20:51 mpeg_encode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6496 Nov 29 21:01 mri_dicom_stuff.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    90294 Nov 29 21:01 mrilib.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3434886 Nov 29 20:43 mritopgm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2696 Nov 29 21:01 mri_warpfield.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1986 Nov 29 21:01 multivector.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6890 Nov 29 20:51 mycat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3434851 Nov 29 20:51 myget
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11095 Nov 29 21:01 neuro_deconvolve.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3435203 Nov 29 20:46 nicat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3439008 Nov 29 20:48 niccc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    69232 Nov 29 21:01 nifti1.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    25666 Nov 29 21:01 nifti1_io.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   118029 Nov 29 20:47 nifti1_test
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8385 Nov 29 21:01 nifticdf.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   202223 Nov 29 20:46 nifti_tool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3452960 Nov 29 20:48 niml_feedme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    49354 Nov 29 21:01 niml.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      797 Nov 29 21:01 @NoExt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     7876 Nov 29 21:01 @NoisySkullStrip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1619 Nov 29 21:01 @NoPound
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3189 Nov 29 21:01 @np
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3434883 Nov 29 20:43 nsize
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    19944 Nov 29 21:01 option_list.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    15044 Nov 30 14:40 option_list.pyc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      636 Nov 29 21:01 @parse_afni_name
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      565 Nov 29 21:01 @parse_name
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11253274 Nov 29 21:01 ParseName
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   317923 Nov 29 20:33 paxinos_elsevier_tissue_lores+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5076 Nov 29 20:33 paxinos_elsevier_tissue_lores+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     9467 Nov 29 20:52 plug_3ddot.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    19628 Nov 29 20:52 plug_3Ddump_V2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8459 Nov 29 20:52 plug_3ddup.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   446917 Nov 29 20:53 plug_3dsvm.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    24075 Nov 29 20:52 plug_4Ddump.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    24403 Nov 29 20:52 plug_afnihistory.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    19302 Nov 29 20:53 plug_aslA3D3.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    28239 Nov 29 20:52 plug_betafit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    13850 Nov 29 20:52 plug_clust.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6749 Nov 29 20:52 plug_compress.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8651 Nov 29 20:52 plug_coorder.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11543 Nov 29 20:52 plug_copy.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   373154 Nov 29 20:53 plug_crender.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    59351 Nov 29 20:52 plug_deconvolve.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    45070 Nov 29 20:53 plug_delay_V2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   104311 Nov 29 20:52 plug_drawdset.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    28058 Nov 29 20:52 plug_edit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    20423 Nov 29 20:53 plug_extract.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    16036 Nov 29 20:53 plug_fourier.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     9410 Nov 29 20:53 plug_hemisub.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    18399 Nov 29 20:52 plug_histog_multi.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    32771 Nov 29 20:52 plug_histog.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    13098 Nov 29 20:52 plug_imreg.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    13511 Nov 29 20:52 plug_L1fit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    20026 Nov 29 20:52 plug_lsqfit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    17777 Nov 29 20:52 plug_maskave.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    20984 Nov 29 20:53 plug_maskcalc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    60485 Nov 29 20:53 plug_maxima.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    72383 Nov 29 20:52 plug_nlfit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    34478 Nov 29 20:52 plug_notes.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    22417 Nov 29 20:52 plug_nth_dataset.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    54029 Nov 29 20:52 plug_nudge.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3443823 Nov 29 20:47 plugout_drive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3439465 Nov 29 20:44 plugout_ijk
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3439492 Nov 29 20:44 plugout_tt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3444047 Nov 29 20:43 plugout_tta
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    37831 Nov 29 20:53 plug_permtest.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    18348 Nov 29 20:52 plug_power.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   146125 Nov 29 20:52 plug_realtime.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8869 Nov 29 20:52 plug_rename.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4273 Nov 29 20:52 plug_render.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    24899 Nov 29 20:53 plug_reorder.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    27546 Nov 29 20:53 plug_retroicor.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   187812 Nov 29 20:53 plug_roiedit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    15365 Nov 29 20:52 plug_roiplot.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    19929 Nov 29 20:52 plug_scatplot.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    19544 Nov 29 20:52 plug_second_dataset.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8731 Nov 29 20:52 plug_stats.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    15797 Nov 29 20:53 plug_stavg.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    42441 Nov 29 20:52 plug_tag.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    14919 Nov 29 20:53 plug_threshold.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4274 Nov 29 20:52 plug_ttget.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    44427 Nov 29 20:53 plug_vol2surf.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    24159 Nov 29 20:52 plug_volreg.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    28108 Nov 29 20:52 plug_wavelets.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    10030 Nov 29 20:52 plug_zeropad.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11308903 Nov 29 21:01 prompt_user
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1783 Nov 29 21:01 @Purify_1D
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8289 Nov 29 21:01 python_module_test.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   298646 Nov 29 20:45 qdelaunay
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   302292 Nov 29 20:45 qhull
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1909 Nov 29 21:01 quick.alpha.vals.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11257559 Nov 29 21:01 quickspec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8523 Nov 29 21:01 @Quiet_Talkers
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    19607 Nov 29 21:01 @radial_correlate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   292354 Nov 29 20:45 rbox
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1511 Nov 29 21:01 rcmat.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     2402 Nov 29 21:01 README.3dsvm.realtime
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    14096 Nov 29 21:01 README.afnigui
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     6080 Nov 29 21:01 README.atlas_building
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    45863 Nov 29 21:01 README.attributes
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    46932 Nov 29 21:01 README.bzip2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2194 Nov 29 20:33 README.caez_atlas_build
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner      476 Nov 29 21:01 README.changes
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     4707 Nov 29 21:01 README.compression
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    25610 Nov 29 21:01 README.copyright
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    30919 Nov 29 21:01 README.driver
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner   173673 Nov 29 21:01 README.environment
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     5657 Nov 29 21:01 README.func_types
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner      587 Nov 29 21:01 README.Ifile
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     6451 Nov 29 21:01 README.notes
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     1684 Nov 29 21:01 README.permtest
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner      553 Nov 29 21:01 README.plugouts
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    18268 Nov 29 21:01 README.realtime
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner    31330 Nov 29 21:01 README.registration
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     7415 Nov 29 21:01 README.render_scripts
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     6842 Nov 29 21:01 README.roi
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     9487 Nov 29 21:01 README.setup
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     6113 Nov 29 21:01 README.volreg
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     1649 Nov 29 21:01 README.web
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner        0 Nov 29 21:01 README.ziad
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    22443 Nov 29 21:01 realtime_receiver.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    12487 Nov 29 21:01 @RenamePanga
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6826 Nov 29 21:01 @Reorder
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    69275 Nov 29 21:01 @RetinoProc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1010 Nov 29 21:01 @R_funclist
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1161 Nov 29 21:01 r_idisp.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  4891010 Nov 29 20:40 R_io.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      742 Nov 29 21:01 r_misc.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3434934 Nov 29 20:51 rmz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      830 Nov 29 21:01 r_new_resam_dset.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11261471 Nov 29 21:01 ROI2dataset
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    16964 Nov 29 21:01 @ROI_Corr_Mat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11318872 Nov 29 21:01 ROIgrow
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3473422 Nov 29 20:46 rotcom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3448411 Nov 29 20:44 RSFgen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3446887 Nov 29 20:46 rtfeedme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11261647 Nov 29 21:01 SampBias
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11267819 Nov 29 21:01 ScaleToMap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    10283 Nov 29 21:01 @ScaleVolume
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      305 Nov 29 20:33 scan_niml_vals.csh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3813 Nov 29 21:01 @ScriptCheck
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    28744 Nov 29 20:46 serial_helper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3443924 Nov 29 20:43 sfim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5491 Nov 29 21:01 @Shift_Volume
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2943 Nov 29 21:01 @ShowDynamicRange
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3439042 Nov 29 20:46 siemens_vision
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    21966 Nov 29 21:01 Signatures.R
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    27916 Nov 29 21:01 @simulate_motion
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    12546 Nov 29 21:01 slow_surf_clustsim.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1063 Nov 29 21:01 smooth.R
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11284079 Nov 29 21:01 SpharmDeco
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6649 Nov 29 21:01 @Spharm.examples
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11275248 Nov 29 21:01 SpharmReco
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     7612 Nov 29 20:43 sqwave
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1128 Nov 29 21:01 @statauxcode
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3439004 Nov 29 20:45 strblast
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 12036076 Nov 29 21:01 suma
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    46630 Nov 29 21:01 @SUMA_AlignToExperiment
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4454 Nov 29 21:01 suma_change_spec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3663 Nov 29 21:01 @SUMA_FSvolToBRIK
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    16282 Nov 29 21:01 SUMA_glxdino
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    30640 Nov 29 21:01 @SUMA_Make_Spec_Caret
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    43418 Nov 29 21:01 @SUMA_Make_Spec_FS
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    20693 Nov 29 21:01 @SUMA_Make_Spec_SF
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1196794 Nov 29 21:01 SUMA_paperplane
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    16235 Nov 29 21:01 SUMA_pixmap2eps
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11319879 Nov 29 21:01 Surf2VolCoord
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11288478 Nov 29 21:01 SurfaceMetrics
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11265699 Nov 29 21:01 SurfClust
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11260459 Nov 29 21:01 SurfDist
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11307483 Nov 29 21:01 SurfDsetInfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11313913 Nov 29 21:01 SurfExtrema
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11325245 Nov 29 21:01 SurfFWHM
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11309999 Nov 29 21:01 SurfInfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11335258 Nov 29 21:01 SurfMeasures
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11721032 Nov 29 21:01 SurfMesh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11268881 Nov 29 21:01 SurfPatch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11261872 Nov 29 21:01 SurfQual
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11318969 Nov 29 21:01 SurfRetinoMap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11323055 Nov 29 21:01 SurfSmooth
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11984 Nov 29 21:01 @SurfSmooth.HEAT_07.examples
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner 11330294 Nov 29 21:01 SurfToSurf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    10077 Nov 29 21:01 @T1scale
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1938 Nov 29 21:01 tagset.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3444177 Nov 29 20:43 tfim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6453 Nov 29 21:01 thd_atlas.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3010 Nov 29 21:01 thd_compress.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5926 Nov 29 21:01 thd_iochan.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1678 Nov 29 21:01 thd_maker.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1052 Nov 29 21:01 thd_ttatlas_CA_EZ.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    28648 Nov 29 21:01 thd_ttatlas_query.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     1106 Nov 29 21:01 @TimeDiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    64032 Nov 29 21:01 timing_tool.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  6070158 Nov 29 20:43 to3d
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3729 Nov 29 21:01 @toMNI_Awarp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    16674 Nov 29 21:01 @toMNI_Qwarpar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     2004 Nov 29 21:01 @ToRAI
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   377624 Nov 29 20:33 TTatlas+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    40896 Nov 29 20:33 TTatlas+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   794290 Nov 29 20:33 TT_avg152T1+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4932 Nov 29 20:33 TT_avg152T1+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   781798 Nov 29 20:33 TT_avg152T2+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     5440 Nov 29 20:33 TT_avg152T2+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1356732 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_colin27_T1_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8799 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_colin27_T1_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  2928274 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_gw_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8473 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_gw_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   151399 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_lr_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8585 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_lr_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   230450 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_ml_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    23852 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_ml_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   197143 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_mpm_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    17687 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_mpm_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  2953181 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_pmaps_18+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    23949 Nov 29 20:33 TT_caez_pmaps_18+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   138445 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_dd_mpm+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    35035 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_dd_mpm+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3519331 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_ddpmaps+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   214682 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_ddpmaps+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   131991 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_dk_mpm+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    21386 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_dk_mpm+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  2419046 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_dkpmaps+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   128396 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_dkpmaps+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1568559 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_fspmaps+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   112365 Nov 29 20:33 TT_desai_fspmaps+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   791958 Nov 29 20:33 TT_EPI+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     4897 Nov 29 20:33 TT_EPI+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  2184281 Nov 29 20:33 TT_icbm452+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     8730 Nov 29 20:33 TT_icbm452+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   701987 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_CA_EZ_MPM+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    12387 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_CA_EZ_MPM+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   552746 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_CA_EZ_PMaps+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    18436 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_CA_EZ_PMaps+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    59999 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_EZ_LR+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11839 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_EZ_LR+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner   114420 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_EZ_ML+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    15625 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27_EZ_ML+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  1353925 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27+tlrc.BRIK.gz
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    11447 Nov 29 20:33 TT_N27+tlrc.HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     9891 Nov 29 21:01 uber_align_test.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    10798 Nov 29 21:01 uber_proc.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    10002 Nov 29 21:01 uber_skel.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    19585 Nov 29 21:01 uber_subject.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    12252 Nov 29 21:01 uber_ttest.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    45044 Nov 29 21:01 ui_xmat.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 owner owner     4784 Nov 29 20:33 UNC_infant_CustomAtlases.niml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6186 Nov 29 21:01 @UpdateAfni
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    14894 Nov 29 21:01 @update.afni.binaries
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    34890 Nov 29 21:01 vecmat.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3578702 Nov 29 20:45 Vecwarp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     6508 Nov 29 21:01 vol2surf.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3150 Nov 29 21:01 @VolCenter
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    25376 Nov 29 21:01 volpack.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3453741 Nov 29 20:43 waver
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  3912691 Nov 29 20:47 whereami
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner    17987 Nov 29 20:51 whirlgif
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner      453 Nov 29 21:01 xmat_tool.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner  5943491 Nov 29 20:51 Xphace
-rwxr-xr-x 1 owner owner     3056 Nov 29 21:01 znzlib.h
ubuntu:~>
```

And I don't know if this is all of it. Is it supposed to be this long?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/owner/abin`?

Answer (score 0):

They really want to make your life difficult. You must use tcsh to use the program. Type `tcsh` then write `afni` and `suma`. You must do this each time.

```
set path = ($path /home/owner/abin)

tcsh
afni
suma
```

Comment: still says command not found